# Text in a custom view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, view

I am trying to create a view with a text in it and in future more elements to this view.

Now I tried a couple of things reading old posts on Stack Overflow, but fail to display the text in my current view.

**TaskView.java**

```
public class TaskView extends View {

CharSequence text;


public TaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attributes, R.styleable.TaskView);

    try {

        text = typedArray.getText(R.styleable.TaskView_android_text);

    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources >
  <declare-styleable name="TaskView">
    <attr name="android:text" />
    <attr name="android:textSize" />

  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:costum="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.application.arjan.notes.Planner.TaskView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundOrangeLight"
    android:text="Hello!!!"       **Can't see this text**
    android:textSize="20dp"
    costum:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    costum:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    costum:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    costum:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

</com.application.arjan.notes.Planner.TaskView>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can't find my mistake, I also tried with costum properties (like only text, without android) and adding format=string to the attrs property.
When I display this view I only see a square with the defined backgroundcolor...

Comment: `View` doesn't know anything about text, so if you do mean to be extending that class specifically, you'll need to handle tracking and drawing that text yourself. However, if you're trying to make something like a `TextView` with extra bells and whistles, then perhaps you'd rather extend `TextView` instead.

Comment: Thx, do you mean using a Canvas drawing by tracking and drawing?

Comment: Well, for "tracking", I just meant the `text` field you already have, and any necessary setter method, getter, etc. As for drawing, yeah, it will involve a `Canvas`, and if you override the `onDraw()` method, the `Canvas` you need to eventually draw to is passed into that method.

Comment: So the text attribute I am defining in attrs.xml is useless? Or is it i.e. for methods like setText() and so on?

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean. In the posted code, you're declaring, setting, and retrieving the value correctly, but you're not doing anything with it, and neither is `View`, so in that sense, yeah, it kinda is. Also, if you're asking if it's useless when extending `TextView` instead, then again yeah, kinda, because you could just call `getText()` any time after the `super` constructor call to get that value, and not have to deal with the custom attribute or `TypedArray`.

Answer (score 2):

You must draw your text manually inside TaskView class.
First define your Paint:

```
Paint textPaint;
textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textPaint.setColor(textColor);
```

Then Draw it:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);


   // Draw the label text
   canvas.drawText(text, 0.0, 0.0, textPaint);
}
```

For more options see the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing#java)

Comment: Ok, but how can I then use the text attribute which I defined in attrs.xml? Is it for using methods like setText() and so on or is it useless then when I draw the Text through canvas?

Comment: you can change some attributes like font size, color and style by changing your paint attributes. but, others are useless when you draw it.